# jquery droppable - nested divs, get target id

Tags: jquery-ui, droppable, jquery-ui-droppable, jquery-droppable

I have something like this:

```
$('#mover' ).draggable({});
$('div').droppable({
    drop: function(event, ui) {
        console.log(event.target.id)
    }
```

then

```
<div id="container">
    <div id="target_1"></div>
    <div id="target_2"></div>
    <div id="target_3"></div>
</div>
```

When I drop mover on a div "container" is returned.  how do I return instead the lowest child that the item was dropped on?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I know the solution to the actual problem: I was trying to drop an element on same div that it came from.